# Use Gephi to display graphs in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic, gephi

I've created an agent based model in AnyLogic and would like to visualize the graph. Ideally I'd like to use something like Gephi.

I've used the general visualization tools that come with AnyLogic to create a circle layout, but I'd much rather have something that is more useful, such as the Force Atlas 2.

Ideally, I'd like to have the graph visualized directly in one of the view areas. Any ideas? It seems that AnyLogic is awfully limiting in what you can do visually outside of its pre-packaged components (as vast as they are in their own right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that Gephi is a powerful tool for working with graphs, but I haven`t directly used it in AnyLogic so far. 
Here is how I would try do it:

1. Download the [Gephi Toolkit](https://gephi.org/toolkit/) as a Java jar
2. Integrate it in your AnyLogic project: In the Project tab in your model's properties under *Dependencies* / Jar files and class folders add the downloaded jar file
3. Add the namespaces to your project by adding in your Main under *Advanced Java* / *Imports Section* (Here the example for the needed namespaces to generate graphs):

```
import org.openide.util.Lookup;
import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.Container;
import org.gephi.io.generator.plugin.RandomGraph;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.ImportController;
import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.DefaultProcessor;
import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.AppendProcessor;
import org.gephi.io.generator.plugin.DynamicGraph;
```

4. Generate a graph, described in [this example](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/How-to-generate-graphs).

The only difficult or impossible thing might be integrating visualisation into the AnyLogic canvas. However you can always have a "popup" window as a JFrame as in [this example](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/How-to-reuse-the-Preview-Applet).

Comment: So I marked this answer as accepted. Eventually I gave up as the client was happy with a different solution. However, this answer got me closest. It does appear that the popup option is the only way, as the AnyLogic canvas doesn't appear to be able to visualize something with gephi. I've given this thought and think that there are other ways of using parts of gephi to get it done, but its probably faster to just hack it together to visualize outside of AnyLogic (perhaps with AnyLogic updating node and link values but not visualizing) than it is to do it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Gephi is but you can load any Java library into AnyLogic and use it. There are tons out there for vis, even 3D charts are possible.

So you are not limited by AnyLogic but by Java... which really isn't that much of a limitation ;-)

(Check AnyLogic help on how to load jar files)